Can you use scripting to save the intensity of Light reaching a Face to a CSV file?


As depicted in the photo, I have placed a Light Object below and a Face above. The Face is divided into 16 sections as an example. In this setup, each of the 16 Faces receives a different light intensity from the Light Object.
I want to save the information on the light received by each of these 16 Faces into a CSV file. In reality, I plan to divide the Face into numerous smaller segments.
How should I write a Python script to solve this process?

Hello ! I don't think the information is readibly available but you can try baking the material to a texture and count the bright pixels relative to the dark pixels, or average the pixel values depending on the result you want

Thank you for the good answer. I'm currently analyzing using the brightness differences in the image as you suggested. I'm using the method of sending it to Python and then converting it to CSV. However, I wanted to do this all at once using Blender's script...
